# T-SQL Hierarchical Json Result for Employee Org Chart

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to output hierarchical JSON from a SQL Server database for a company org chart.

I would like to display the data in something like https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart.

I have been able to build a query that outputs the hierarchy into a flat table as follows:

[image]

I was able to achieve what I wanted by using FOR JSON PATH but this will only really give me the data I need to a single level of hierarchy.

Would anyone know how to have multiple levels of hierarchy outputted from T-SQL to give me something like the following output:

```
 {
          'name': 'Lao Lao',
          'title': 'general manager',
          'children': [
            { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager',
              'children': [
                { 'name': 'Tie Hua', 'title': 'senior engineer' },
                { 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer',
                  'children': [
                    { 'name': 'Pang Pang', 'title': 'engineer' },
                    { 'name': 'Xiang Xiang', 'title': 'UE engineer'
            'children': [
                {'name': 'Pang Pang2', 'title': 'engineer'},
                {'name': 'Pang Pang3', 'title': 'engineer'}
            ] 
            }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            { 'name': 'Yu Jie', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Yu Li', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Hong Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Yu Wei', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Chun Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
            { 'name': 'Yu Tie', 'title': 'department manager' }
          ]
        }
      });
```

I have been trying for multiple hours now and I am no closer to a solution and nothing on the web seems to be able to help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL and consumable data helps us help you. An image of partial data with no data types doesn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate hierarchical JSON data with Microsoft SQL Server 2016?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38298659/90527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a very good article that helped me to achieve what I needed to do.
It is not the fastest solution but it works
[Representing a simple hierarchical list in SQL](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/71858/)

This Microsoft guide was also very helpful: [Hierarchical Structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/lesson-1-converting-a-table-to-a-hierarchical-structure?view=sql-server-ver15)

With both these guides I was able to build something that works, I still need to clean up the code but here is what I ended up with in case this helps anyone else out there.

```
  IF(OBJECT_ID('dbo.Org') IS NOT NULL)
DROP TABLE dbo.Org;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Org  
(  
    OrgNode hierarchyid,  
    Id int,  
    FullName nvarchar(500),  
    ManagerId int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Org_OrgNode  
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (OrgNode)  
);

DECLARE @Children TABLE (
    Id int,  
    ManagerId int,  
    Num int  
);

INSERT @Children (Id, ManagerId, Num)  
SELECT Id, ManagerId,  
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ManagerId ORDER BY ManagerId)   
FROM dbo.Employees;  

WITH paths(path, Id)   
AS (  
SELECT hierarchyid::GetRoot() AS OrgNode, Id   
FROM @Children AS C  
WHERE Id = <CEO ID>
UNION ALL   
SELECT   
CAST(p.path.ToString() + CAST(C.Num AS varchar(30)) + '/' AS hierarchyid),   
C.Id  
FROM @Children AS C   
JOIN paths AS p   
   ON C.ManagerId = P.Id
   AND C.ManagerId <> C.Id
)  
INSERT dbo.Org (OrgNode, O.Id, O.FullName, O.ManagerId)  
SELECT P.path, O.Id, O.UserPrincipalName, O.ManagerId  
FROM dbo.Employees AS O   
JOIN Paths AS P   
   ON O.Id = P.Id  
OPTION (maxrecursion 10000);

IF Object_Id('dbo.JSONHierarchicalListOfReports', 'FN') IS NOT null
  DROP FUNCTION dbo.JSONHierarchicalListOfReports;
GO
/* create the function that creates a JSON representation of the hierarchy */
CREATE FUNCTION JSONHierarchicalListOfReports(@Me HIERARCHYID)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
  BEGIN
    RETURN
      (SELECT 
         Coalesce((SELECT '{'+
            '"name":"' +String_Escape(me.FullName, 'json')+'","title":"' + String_Escape(me.FullName, 'json') + '","children":['+Stuff( --get a list of reports
                (SELECT ',' + dbo.JSONHierarchicalListOfReports(reports.OrgNode)
                    FROM dbo.Org AS reports
                    WHERE reports.OrgNode.GetAncestor(1) = me.OrgNode
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),1, 1,'')+']}'
         ),'{"name":"'+String_Escape(me.FullName, 'json')+'","title":"'+String_Escape('JOB TITLE HERE', 'json')+'"}') AS reports
         FROM dbo.Org AS me
          WHERE me.OrgNode = @Me
      );
  END;
GO

SELECT dbo.JSONHierarchicalListOfReports(OrgNode)
  FROM dbo.Org
  where dbo.Org.Id = <CEO ID>
```

This then outputs something like this: (obviously I can't post the real data as that is confidential)

```
{"name":"abc@abc.com","title":"Manger","children":[{"name":"test.user5555@abc.com","title:":"Worker"}]}
```