# JSON for Tree Hierarchy Diagram from SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, d3.js

My goal is to prepare the necessary json for a d3.js tree diagram using sql server (2019). I'm using the sql below to allow up to six node levels. It builds a json string but the output requires editing because the d3.js diagram requires all the children nodes to be named "children".

```
declare @t table (nodeName varchar(50), name varchar(50), parentname varchar(50), type varchar(50), code varchar(50), label varchar(50), version varchar(50));
insert into @t(nodeName,name,parentname,type,code,label,version)
values

('NODE NAME 1','NODE NAME 1','','type3','N1','Node name 1','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 2.1','NODE NAME 2.1','NODE NAME 1','type1','N2.1','Node name 2.1','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 2.2','NODE NAME 2.2','NODE NAME 1','type1','N2.2','Node name 2.2','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 2.3','NODE NAME 2.3','NODE NAME 1','type1','N2.3','Node name 2.3','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 2.4','NODE NAME 2.4','NODE NAME 1','type1','N2.4','Node name 2.4','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 2.5','NODE NAME 2.5','NODE NAME 1','type1','N2.5','Node name 2.5','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 3.1','NODE NAME 3.1','NODE NAME 2.1','type2','N3.1','Node name 3.1','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 3.2','NODE NAME 3.2','NODE NAME 2.1','type2','N3.2','Node name 3.2','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 3.3','NODE NAME 3.3','NODE NAME 2.3','type1','N3.3','Node name 3.3','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 3.4','NODE NAME 3.4','NODE NAME 2.3','type1','N3.4','Node name 3.4','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 3.5','NODE NAME 3.5','NODE NAME 2.4','type2','N3.5','Node name 3.5','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 3.6','NODE NAME 3.6','NODE NAME 2.5','type2','N3.6','Node name 3.6','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 4.1','NODE NAME 4.1','NODE NAME 3.3','type4','N4.1','Node name 4.1','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 4.2','NODE NAME 4.2','NODE NAME 3.4','type4','N4.2','Node name 4.2','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 5.1','NODE NAME 5.1','NODE NAME 4.1','type4','N5.1','Node name 5.1','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 5.2','NODE NAME 5.2','NODE NAME 4.1','type4','N5.2','Node name 5.2','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 6.1','NODE NAME 6.1','NODE NAME 5.2','type4','N6.1','Node name 6.1','v1.0'),
('NODE NAME 6.2','NODE NAME 6.2','NODE NAME 5.2','type4','N6.2','Node name 6.2','v1.0');

with l1 as (select * from @t where nodename = 'NODE NAME 1')
,l2 as (select * from @t where parentname in (select nodename from l1))
,l3 as (select * from @t where parentname in (select nodename from l2))
,l4 as (select * from @t where parentname in (select nodename from l3))
,l5 as (select * from @t where parentname in (select nodename from l4))
,l6 as (select * from @t where parentname in (select nodename from l5))

select l1.*, l2.*, l3.*, l4.*, l5.*, l6.*
from l1 
left join l2 on l2.parentname = l1.nodename
left join l3 on l3.parentname = l2.nodename
left join l4 on l4.parentname = l3.nodename
left join l5 on l5.parentname = l4.nodename
left join l6 on l6.parentname = l5.nodename

for json auto
```

Resulting json:

```
"nodeName": "NODE NAME 1",
"name": "NODE NAME 1",
"parentname": "",
"type": "type3",
"code": "N1",
"label": "Node name 1",
"version": "v1.0",
"l2": [
    {
        "nodeName": "NODE NAME 2.1",
        "name": "NODE NAME 2.1",
        "parentname": "NODE NAME 1",
        "type": "type1",
        "code": "N2.1",
        "label": "Node name 2.1",
        "version": "v1.0",
        "l3": [
            {
                "nodeName": "NODE NAME 3.1",
                "name": "NODE NAME 3.1",
                "parentname": "NODE NAME 2.1",
                "type": "type2",
                "code": "N3.1",
                "label": "Node name 3.1",
                "version": "v1.0",
                "l4": [
                    {
                        "l5": [
                            {
                                "l6": [
                                    {}
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Edited to work:

```
"nodeName": "NODE NAME 1",
"name": "NODE NAME 1",
"parentname": "",
"type": "type3",
"code": "N1",
"label": "Node name 1",
"version": "v1.0",
"children": [
    {
        "nodeName": "NODE NAME 2.1",
        "name": "NODE NAME 2.1",
        "parentname": "NODE NAME 1",
        "type": "type1",
        "code": "N2.1",
        "label": "Node name 2.1",
        "version": "v1.0",
        "children": [
            {
                "nodeName": "NODE NAME 3.1",
                "name": "NODE NAME 3.1",
                "parentname": "NODE NAME 2.1",
                "type": "type2",
                "code": "N3.1",
                "label": "Node name 3.1",
                "version": "v1.0",
                "children": []
            },
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to write the query to avoid this editing.

Comment: Have you considered subqueries instead of left joins? i.e.: `JSON_QUERY(( /*subquery producing JSON here*/ )) as children`

Comment: Is there a maximum possible depth or can there be an arbitrary number of levels?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Thanks! I was hoping to avoid going there but I suspect that approach could/would work. I'll first try out what Charlieface posted

Comment: @Charlieface -  Thanks! The data, which is scheduling related with activities having predecessors/successors, goes to 20 levels, but for the purposes of the diagram I'm planning to clip it 10 levels. I'll give your UDF a try!

Comment: See also various answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72706539/create-json-with-childrens-in-sql-server-structure-for-web-tree

Comment: Your solution is simply outstanding, but I've now had to add another branch to each node that configures the link-line between them. I looked at the link above but lack the depth of understanding to apply what is shared there. Thanks to your help, I'm so close to having this working. Can I share the modified json now required here ... or should it be a new question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this (without resorting to an iterative cursor-style solution) is to use a scalar User Defined Function which recurses down to get all levels of the JSON

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetJson ( @name varchar(50) )
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (
    SELECT
      nodeName,
      name,
      parentname,
      type,
      code,
      label,
      version,
      JSON_QUERY(dbo.GetJson(name)) AS children
    FROM dbo.t
    WHERE t.parentname = @name
    FOR JSON PATH
  );
END;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/LeNSQ_g1)

**Result**

```
[
   {
      "nodeName":"NODE NAME 1",
      "name":"NODE NAME 1",
      "parentname":"",
      "type":"type3",
      "code":"N1",
      "label":"Node name 1",
      "version":"v1.0",
      "children":[
         {
            "nodeName":"NODE NAME 2.1",
            "name":"NODE NAME 2.1",
            "parentname":"NODE NAME 1",
            "type":"type1",
            "code":"N2.1",
            "label":"Node name 2.1",
            "version":"v1.0",
            "children":[
               {
                  "nodeName":"NODE NAME 3.1",
                  "name":"NODE NAME 3.1",
                  "parentname":"NODE NAME 2.1",
                  "type":"type2",
                  "code":"N3.1",
                  "label":"Node name 3.1",
                  "version":"v1.0"
               },
               {
                  "nodeName":"NODE NAME 3.2",
                  "name":"NODE NAME 3.2",
                  "parentname":"NODE NAME 2.1",
                  "type":"type2",
                  "code":"N3.2",
                  "label":"Node name 3.2",
                  "version":"v1.0"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "nodeName":"NODE NAME 2.2",
            "name":"NODE NAME 2.2",
            "parentname":"NODE NAME 1",
            "type":"type1",
            "code":"N2.2",
            "label":"Node name 2.2",
            "version":"v1.0"
         },
         {
            "nodeName":"NODE NAME 2.3",
            "name":"NODE NAME 2.3",
            "parentname":"NODE NAME 1",
            "type":"type1",
            "code":"N2.3",
            "label":"Node name 2.3",
            "version":"v1.0",
            "children":[
               {
                  "nodeName":"NODE NAME 3.3",
                  "name":"NODE NAME 3.3",
                  "parentname":"NODE NAME 2.3",
                  "type":"type1",
                  "code":"N3.3",
                  "label":"Node name 3.3",
                  "version":"v1.0",
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "nodeName":"NODE NAME 4.1",
                        "name":"NODE NAME 4.1",
                        "parentname":"NODE NAME 3.3",
                        "type":"type4",
                        "code":"N4.1",
                        "label":"Node name 4.1",
                        "version":"v1.0",
                        "children":[
                           {
                              "nodeName":"NODE NAME 5.1",
                              "name":"NODE NAME 5.1",
                              "parentname":"NODE NAME 4.1",
                              "type":"type4",
                              "code":"N5.1",
                              "label":"Node name 5.1",
                              "version":"v1.0"
                           },
                           {
                              "nodeName":"NODE NAME 5.2",
                              "name":"NODE NAME 5.2",
                              "parentname":"NODE NAME 4.1",
                              "type":"type4",
                              "code":"N5.2",
                              "label":"Node name 5.2",
                              "version":"v1.0",
                              "children":[
                                 {
                                    "nodeName":"NODE NAME 6.1",
                                    "name":"NODE NAME 6.1",
                                    "parentname":"NODE NAME 5.2",
                                    "type":"type4",
                                    "code":"N6.1",
                                    "label":"Node name 6.1",
                                    "version":"v1.0"
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "nodeName":"NODE NAME 6.2",
                                    "name":"NODE NAME 6.2",
                                    "parentname":"NODE NAME 5.2",
                                    "type":"type4",
                                    "code":"N6.2",
                                    "label":"Node name 6.2",
                                    "version":"v1.0"
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "nodeName":"NODE NAME 3.4",
                  "name":"NODE NAME 3.4",
                  "parentname":"NODE NAME 2.3",
                  "type":"type1",
                  "code":"N3.4",
                  "label":"Node name 3.4",
                  "version":"v1.0",
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "nodeName":"NODE NAME 4.2",
                        "name":"NODE NAME 4.2",
                        "parentname":"NODE NAME 3.4",
                        "type":"type4",
                        "code":"N4.2",
                        "label":"Node name 4.2",
                        "version":"v1.0"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "nodeName":"NODE NAME 2.4",
            "name":"NODE NAME 2.4",
            "parentname":"NODE NAME 1",
            "type":"type1",
            "code":"N2.4",
            "label":"Node name 2.4",
            "version":"v1.0",
            "children":[
               {
                  "nodeName":"NODE NAME 3.5",
                  "name":"NODE NAME 3.5",
                  "parentname":"NODE NAME 2.4",
                  "type":"type2",
                  "code":"N3.5",
                  "label":"Node name 3.5",
                  "version":"v1.0"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "nodeName":"NODE NAME 2.5",
            "name":"NODE NAME 2.5",
            "parentname":"NODE NAME 1",
            "type":"type1",
            "code":"N2.5",
            "label":"Node name 2.5",
            "version":"v1.0",
            "children":[
               {
                  "nodeName":"NODE NAME 3.6",
                  "name":"NODE NAME 3.6",
                  "parentname":"NODE NAME 2.5",
                  "type":"type2",
                  "code":"N3.6",
                  "label":"Node name 3.6",
                  "version":"v1.0"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Much thanks! This looks very promising! I will test shortly.

Comment: When I try this in SSMS I only get the first node to form with the rest as a string.

Does it need to be executed in a batch?

Comment: Are you using `JSON_QUERY` like I did? Can you show a fiddle of your code?